# Get the intersection of a django queryset with a __in

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

So I have an array and a queryset.

some_array = [...]

queryset = queryset.filter(some_field__in=some_array)

Actually it returns every object that the "some_field" is in the array. What I want is only the objects that have all the fields from the array.

Thx

Comment: What type of field is `some_field`in your example? Is is an array?

Comment: Share your actual code instead of sharing examples.